# Cakephp 3 find('list')

Tags: find, cakephp-3.0

I wanted to prefill a multiple Checkbox form with Data from MySql Database.

My Database Data :

```
id  customer_id     language_id     preferred
1   10              150             yes
2   10              149             yes
```

The query in Controller "Preferredcustomerlanguages"

```
$clientlanguages = $this->Preferredcustomerlanguages
        ->find('list')
        ->select(['language_id'])
        ->where(['customer_id =' => $customer_id])
        ->where(['preferred =' => 'yes'])
        ->toArray()
    ;
```

If i start the query with $customer_id = 10 the result is this:

```
[
(int) 2 => (int) 2,
(int) 1 => (int) 1
]
```

I thought the query would give me a list of the language_id which i need to prefill my form.

Maybe someone can give me a hint where iḿ thinking wrong

Comment: Isn't that what the `displayField()` is for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2186596/1604068

Comment: that is the solution. thanks a lot.you made my day!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to select a field different to `displayField`, you can use the list arguments for this:

```
$clientlanguages = $this->Preferredcustomerlanguages
    ->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'id',
        'valueField' => 'language_id'
    ])
    ->where(['customer_id =' => $customer_id])
    ->where(['preferred =' => 'yes'])
    ->toArray();
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs

Comment: `toArray()` made a difference in my case, I was trying `all()` at first and it showed me the count instead of a list as expected, even though the finder type was actually `list`

Comment: When you use ‘->all()’ you get an iterative object. In ‘debug()’ it shows just the count value, but it’s definetly an object that you can use with ‘foreach’.

Comment: You're right, just tried looping through it and it worked. Thank you!